# Why is cosine similarity a lot higher between one document and all other documents grouped than vs the mean of each

Tags: r, cosine-similarity

I am trying to calculate a cosine similarity score for speeches made by various politicians.

Say I have politician A who belongs to party A. Party A has 20 other politicians who have made a total of 50 speeches (documents).

Now I want to calculate each of the politicians' speech cosine similarity to the rest of the speeches from his/her own party.

I calculate a cosine similarly between politician A's speeches (if politician A has more than one speech, I collapse them into one single speech) and all other speeches from the same party and take the average. Then I do that with the next politician until I have done it will them all. In the end, my score lies in the range 0.02 - 0.06 for each politician.

Instead, if I take Party A - politician A's speech and collapse them all into one long speech, and then calculate the cosine similarity between politician A's speech and the other "long" party A speech (comprised of all speeches made from politicians from that party except politician A's speech), and then do that for them all, the score lies in the range 0.17 - 0.4

How come this is the case? Does this make sense? Essentially, the difference:

Speech A compared to all speeches (separately) from party A, followed by calculating the mean of all the scores. The same is done for all speeches (Speech B..C...D..E etc) This way, the score is lower ranging from 0.02 - 0.06 for each politician

vs

Speech A (followed by B..C..D etc) compared to one long speech of party A. This way, the score is higher ranging from 0.17 - 0.4 for each politician

Hope it makes sense

Comment: This is quite difficult to understand. Can you simplify the example, perhaps to just `A`, `B`, and `C` and perhaps use some pseudocode notation? I **think** what you're saying is that `mean(cos_sim(A, B), cos_sim(A, C)) < cos_sim(A, concat(B, C))`. Is that right? Or if not, can you use some clear notation like that?  Sentences like *"Speech A compared to all speeches (separately) from party A, followed by calculating the mean of all the scores"* are hard to know exactly what you mean.

Comment: @GregorThomas, this is exactly what I mean, yes! mean(cos_sim(A, B), cos_sim(A, C), cos_sim(A, D) < cos_sim(A, concat(B, C, D)). Do you know why this is the case? And is one approach better than the other?

Comment: I don't know much about cosine similarity. I'd strongly recommend editing your question - deleting most of the narrative that's there and presenting it succinctly and clearly as in your last comment. I think you'll get help much faster if people can read and understand your question quickly.